# kendoui grid only use create (no delete or update)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: function(options) {
                        $.ajax( {
                            url: "/api/mygetfunction",
                            data: options.data,
                            success: function(result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    update: function (options) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/myupdatefunction",
                            data: options.data,
                            success: function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    destroy: function (options) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/mydestroyfunction",
                            data: options.data, 
                            success: function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    create: function (options) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/mycreatefunction",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: ...
                        });
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read") {
                            return JSON.stringify(options);
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    id: "Id",
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Id: { type: "string" },
                            Description: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                serverPaging: false,
                serverFiltering: false,
                serverSorting: false,
                batch: false
            },
            toolbar: ["create"],
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                 {
                    field: "Description",
                    title: "Description"
                 },
                 { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "210px" }
            ],
            editable: "inline"
        });
```

The grid has 3 rows. When I click on edit, I change the description column. Then I Click Update, and the grid caals the 'create' of the transport configuration. I've set batch to false, and strangely, there are 3 create's instead of the changed row.

What's the reason the editing of the grid causes a create instead of update?

Comment: Never used this feature of Kendo grids.  I'm wondering whether it's related to HTTP POST/PUT requests?

Answer (score 3):

This may happen if your records don't have an `Id` field properly set. The data source considers all records that don't have id to be "new".

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in javascript but from the MVC helper you would need. .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Model(model =>{
model.Id(p => p.<IdFieldInModel>);

Comment: There is id specified in the schema. However I am not sure if your existing data records have that id field set. Check your server response from the "read" setting.

Comment: In my case I had defined the model.Id but on a model Item that I hadn't defined on the grid's columns.